# Graph question. how to determine for each vertex v....

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

1.there is path to every other vertex
2. there is path to only at most 20 vertices

my line of attack

function(G):
    for every vertex v in G

```
     for every vertex u adjacent to v
             do DFS
```

but the function must run in O(V) time

Comment: Think about connected components. You will need a marked array. You will also need a connected component array. Start with vertex 0. On the DFS call, every vertex you touch should be true, and part of the 1st connected component. Once you've reached everywhere that you can, then you should go to the next unmarked vertex, run DFS and put every connected component reachable there in the 2nd connected component. Once you've done this for every vertex to see if there is a path to every other vertex you just have to see if every value of the connected component array is the same. Think along that.

Comment: However, if you plan to use DFS note that DFS has a worst case of O(|E| + |V|). So, to accomplish this with O(|V|) would be difficult and might require some different implementation. (Unless you pre-populate the marked and connected components arrays with their respected values. Then it is trivial).